# Retrieving aria-label value using Selenium's find function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I have the xpath of an element on a website but I'm trying to get the aria-label value of that element.

```
    # NO SUCCESS: print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "element_xpath_you_found"))).get_attribute("aria-label"))
    # NO SUCCESS: first_rev = browser.find_element(By.xpath, "/html/body/span/g-lightbox/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/g-review-stars/span")
    
    first_rev = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/g-lightbox/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/g-review-stars/span").click()
    aria_label = first_rev.find_element_by_css_selector('span').get_attribute("aria-label")
    print(aria_label)
```

On the browser, I inspect the element and get this html:

```
<span class="fTKmHE99XE4__star fTKmHE99XE4__star-s" aria-label="Rated 3.0 out of 5," style=""><span style="width:42px"></span></span>
```

However, can the problem be that this element is inside a pop-up on the page? Page source doesn't show any html for any element in the pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

`click()` doesn't have return value, which means it returns `None`, which make `first_rev` `None`, split it to two actions. You also don't need the `first_rev.find_element`, you are actually getting its child element

```
first_rev = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/g-lightbox/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/g-review-stars/span")
first_rev.click()
aria_label = first_rev.get_attribute("aria-label")
print(aria_label)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns None using this method.

Comment: @AcePash If `get_attribute("aria-label")` return `None` it means the element doesn't have this attribute. To get more assistance you need to post the relevant html.

Comment: I just added the html of the element to the post.

Comment: @AcePash What happens if you do `first_rev.get_attribute("aria-label")`? I'm guessing `first_rev` is the element you want and by doing `first_rev.find_element` you are actually getting its child element.

Comment: OMG, yes it worked. Sometimes, simple is better. Thank you, first_rev.get_attribute("aria-label") yielded the answer.